# Typescript Mixins with dynamic property names

Tags: typescript

I'd like to create a mixin where a property name can be defined. This doesn't work:

```
export declare type AbstractConstructor<T = object> = abstract new (...args: any[]) => T;
export function mixinProperty<T extends AbstractConstructor<any>>(Base: T, propertyName: string) {
    abstract class MixinProperty extends Base {
        ['CustomProperty'] = 1;
        [propertyName] = 2;
    };

    return MixinProperty;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AYwDYEMrDjAnmbAQQCMBnGKdZGAYQgDtyoBXa6AHgBU4BeOCYgCsUMAHy846MhSrx6wAO5wAFADp1mAOakAXJPq4A2gF0AlL3GcA3AFgAUKEiw4AM2b1qASwZwAtp5BPegAFKAgCWFwuOFAYYHoEUjgSJlk6RgpWGA50A1FRZQAhdFJgPU4AGjgwMIi8ADl0XzK4JiDNcwBvezheyWlKajg0EqSAWQCg0PDgSJiQOISk4tK4brs+zbhDAHIaZnIIX2m63B3jCQBGWw2t3sMamcjG5ou+ACYbzYBfG56+rAwZhQehwCaBEK1WZ4G7fIA

Is something similar possible with TS?

Comment: Class and interface declarations don't support dynamic property names; you can express this in the type system but it's uglier.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVZLZN) meet your needs? If so I can maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `class` and `interface` declarations require all property key names to be statically known.  You can't have dynamic property names in there.  This doesn't mean what you're trying to achieve is impossible, but it does mean that you are forced to jump through some hoops in order to do it.  Here's one possible way to do it:

```
function mixinProperty<
    T extends AbstractConstructor<any>,
    K extends string>
    (Base: T, propertyName: K) {

    abstract class MixinProperty extends Base {
        CustomProperty = 1;
        constructor(...args: any) {
            super(...args);
            (this as any)[propertyName] = 2;
        }
    };
    type _MixinProperty = MixinProperty & Record<K, number>;
    return MixinProperty as (
        (abstract new (...args: any) => _MixinProperty) & {
            prototype: _MixinProperty;
        }) & T;
}
```

First, I assume you want the compiler to actually know that the resulting class has a key at the type of `propertyName`, so we need to give `propertyName` a type that's narrower than `string` (because "there's a `string`-valued key in there somewhere" is kind of useless).  Hence we make `mixinProperty()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K` the `string`-constrained type parameter corresponding to the type of `propertyName`.

Then the big change here is that we avoid trying to tell the compiler that `MixinProperty` actually has a key at `propertyName`.  So we remove the [field declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields), and move the initialization into the constructor body (which we have to add), using a `this as any` [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to prevent the compiler from yelling that `this` has no key of type `K`.

When we return `MixinProperty`, we use another type assertion to tell the compiler that the returned class actually does have a property at `K`.  The instance type would be something like `MixinProperty` (the instance type the compiler knows about), as well as `Record<K, number>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  That "as well as" can be represented by an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).  So I've defined the type `_MixinProperty` to be that.

And so we want the return type to be like `typeof MixinProperty` but where the instance type `MixinProperty` is replaced by `_MixinProperty`, which is the type written after `return MixinProperty as`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const C = mixinProperty(class Foo { a = 3 }, "z");
type C = InstanceType<typeof C>;

const c = new C();
console.log(c.CustomProperty.toFixed(0));
console.log(c.a.toFixed(0));
console.log(c.z.toFixed(0));
```

Looks good!  The compiler knows about `z`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?declaration=false#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQQQEYGdEyjEQGEB7AOzxgFcjSYAeAFXgF55SsArcRAPjbwoufIUTxyIAO7wAFADpFsAOY4AXEPLIA2gF0AlGwFMA3AFgAUJYBm1ckQCWFeAFsHADwfkACjFLoYFAZLeFD4FhB3RBByYBx4bCoxMkp8WkR6BigtPgAaELCAaXhI6Nj4qi9lPgLQ2QAhKBwQDSZc+FQ-AJQAOSgXFvhCwwBvS1qhEQIieEgm+IBZDy9ffxBA5BKomLj4Rub4MYswk-hiajxSF1XuzfYARnNj09CwCip0+gUlGFUNbOQowmL1COGoAW+8hUOH0TxBp1kiAAFg54k1NIDtJ01hs+gNdIIAExwkEAXwmpJJoRQ6HgAH0lp4fF11ihBIyViyNvAAGTwABK4HowAYhXa5GoLiw6z4VPgcEQ1Bg5HgHOZOLZ6NkwLCsmESRmkhkkOh-y0hlYAgZy3Vt0MfKO8JO2IyNMG1qZN1ZyDlJ1J9vCT3JVgsb1SZ0Ebk9XJQsjmOHiADFSKRDkJBABmeCk9oAIgAXrnYZY3RH2ABJVLZMAgJhoEAMN2kaxnWXjUPvcRgQRGs6yYsdyikCAgeQQUjKOPyc6Xa4x5DyDKJjwgYCyAAM+gHYZww9H48nYChi9Iy-cq43W6eO73Y4nU-zJ7PF83A-btnsiCcKuTpFFWzKXZKnIapZAAaw0YZDgmLxohgaxCAQX8AJ2eJBTeGARTFCRJWlGABBGYNSSAA)